# How to create a batch file from root folder to install bat files in sub folders

Tags: batch-file

I have three sub folders, each contain different packages and that three packages will install through three different batch files which are present inside of the each folder.Now i need to create a batch file from root folder to install these three batch files.

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a batch file in the root folder, changing the folders and batch files to your folder and files names:

```
call Folder1/install1.bat
call Folder2/install2.bat
call Folder3/install3.bat
```